# Type 'SomeVC' cannot conform to protocol 'NextLevelDelegate' (compiled with Swift 4.1.2)

Tags: ios, swift4.2

Type 'InPersonVideoRecordingVC' cannot conform to protocol '`NextLevelDelegate`' (compiled with `Swift 4.1.2`) because it has requirements that could not be loaded in Swift `3.3.2`

I am using NextLevel Video Recording Library using Cocoapods

This started after i updated to Xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that classes referenced in `NextLevelDelegate` are included in bridging header.

Comment: I thought Xcode automatically handles that. Right? If doesn't, then I have no idea how header files are included. any reference?

Answer (score 0):

You are using NextLevel Video Recording Library which is compiled with **Swift 4.1.2** and it might have some swift version based independencies which is unavailable in your project with **swift version 3.3.2**.

**What to do?**

Try finding the swift 3.3.2 compiled version of NextLevel Video Recording Library, or use another library.

Comment: I used cocoa pods to include the library. If I am right cocoa pods install source code instead of build library. So it should automatically be compiled using 3.3.2. Right?